# Exclude null values in foreach

Tags: php, foreach, null

I need to exclude NULL values from an array with a foreach but it doesn't work actually:

```
   foreach ($node->field_fichier_joint as $key => $fichier) {
       //Ne pas afficher les champs vides du tableau
       if ($fichier !== NULL):
           print 'debug de $fichier'.$fichier;
           print '<li>'.$node->field_fichier_joint[$key]['view'].'</li>';
       endif;
   }
```

This produce empty LI's:

```
    <ul>
   <li>
      <div class="filefield-file clear-block">
            <img class="filefield-icon field-icon-application-pdf" alt="icône application/pdf" src="sites/all/modules/filefield/icons/application-pdf.png">
            <a href="sites/all/media/contenu_international/cal_2sec_20112012.pdf" type="application/pdf; length=39748" title="cal_2sec_20112012.pdf" target="_blank">Fichier test pdf</a>
        </div>
   </li>
   <li>
        <div class="filefield-file clear-block">
            <img class="filefield-icon field-icon-application-pdf" alt="icône application/pdf" src="/sites/all/modules/filefield/icons/application-pdf.png">
            <a href="/sites/all/media/contenu_international/bac_tehno_stg.pdf" type="application/pdf; length=106449" title="bac_tehno_stg.pdf" target="_blank">Fichier test pdf 2</a>
        </div>
   </li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li><a href="https://info.erasmusplus.fr/" target="_blank">Un site internet</a></li>
</ul>
```

What is missing ?

Thanks

EDIt:
`var_dump($fichier);` give for one : `array(1) { ["view"]=> string(0) "" }`
so I need to filter on empty value, not NULL values. Apologize.

EDIT2: Final working code

```
 foreach ($node->field_fichier_joint as $key => $fichier) {
           //Ne pas afficher les champs vides du tableau
           if (!empty($fichier['view'])):
             //  print 'debug de $fichier'.$fichier;
               print '<li>'.$node->field_fichier_joint[$key]['view'].'</li>';
           endif;
       }
```

Comment: Are they null? Or empty strings? What is the output of `var_dump($node->field_fichier_joint)`?

Comment: Maybe you should look at, or show us what `$fichier` may actually contain

Comment: Obviously `$fichier` is not __null__ exactly, but some empty object or something like. `var_dump($fichier)` to check.

Comment: @u_mulder see edit, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, just check if value is not empty with `empty` function:

```
foreach ($node->field_fichier_joint as $key => $fichier) {
   //Ne pas afficher les champs vides du tableau
   if (!empty($fichier['view'])):
       print '<li>' . $fichier['view'] . '</li>';
   endif;
}
```

Comment: Great, I missed a part of the code in my tests with if ``(!empty($fichier)):`` only. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could check the content of `$node->field_fichier_joint[$key]['view']`

```
  foreach ($node->field_fichier_joint as $key => $fichier) {
               //Ne pas afficher les champs vides du tableau
               if ($fichier !== NULL):
                   print 'debug de $fichier'.$fichier;
                print   (isset($node->field_fichier_joint[$key]['view'])) 
                       ?  '<li>'.$node->field_fichier_joint[$key]['view'].'</li>'
                       : '';

            endif;
           }
```

or as suggeted  by B.Desai  use empty() for check also for empty string

```
  foreach ($node->field_fichier_joint as $key => $fichier) {
               //Ne pas afficher les champs vides du tableau
               if ($fichier !== NULL):
                   print 'debug de $fichier'.$fichier;
                print   (!empty($node->field_fichier_joint[$key]['view'])) 
                       ?  '<li>'.$node->field_fichier_joint[$key]['view'].'</li>'
                       : '';

            endif;
           }
```

Comment: yup that's why I have removed my comment :). Hope this answer will accepted too

Answer (score -1):

Just [filter](http://php.net/array_filter) `NULL` values:

```
$values = array_filter($node->field_fichier_joint, 'is_null');

foreach ($values as $key => $fichier) {
     ...
}
```